# Make a swipe button

Tags: ios

I want to make a swipe button, so when user swipe the button from right to left the button also draw towards right to left and at the end it will push the another view, can anybody give sample code for it.

Comment: People will be more inclined to help you out if you accept correct answers for your questions. Also, questions like "i want to do this, give me code" usually aren't met with open arms on SO. Here's a good article on Gesture Recognizers in iOS to get you started: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html

Comment: And just in case you don't know, you click the check mark next to the best answer for your question. It will turn green to let you, and everybody else, know it was the best answer. The person who answers gets reputation points, and you get some points also. Click on your own name and scroll down to see your past questions, some of which have pretty decent answers!

Comment: Please answer any one I can't find the way. Please help me

Comment: Hey paul can you help me for this question.how can I implement swipe on button and how can i drag it please tell me

Comment: No one is here who can answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
// make button  

UIButton*btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
 [self.view addSubview:btn];


// here swipe buttons


- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

    // get delta
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

    // move button
    CGPoint moveBtnCenter = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                                        button.center.y + delta_y);
    button.center = moveBtnCenter;

    NSArray* allSubViews = [self.view subviews];
    for (UIView*subView in allSubViews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            CGPoint subViewCenter = subView.center;
            if (CGPointEqualToPoint(moveBtnCenter, subViewCenter))
            {
                subView.center = previousLocation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```